# What is the reason for using argv[argc + 1] instead of just argv[]

Tags: c

In the book *Modern C* by Jens Gustedt, some example code snippets declare the main function as follows:

```
int main ( int argc , char * argv [ argc +1]) {...
```

This is the first time I have seen a book or tutorial do this.
Are there any differences or advantages between using

```
argv[]
```

and using

```
argv[argc + 1]
```

?

My understanding is that the array `argv` will be automatically created large enough to hold all of the pointers to the arguments given to the program, so I fail to see the purpose of the book’s code.

Comment: The purpose is to make the code self-documenting, so you see it and know that's how many elements are accessible

Comment: @M.M Thank you. This makes sense now.

Comment: "automatically created large enough to hold all of the pointers to the arguments given to the program" and a final one which is `NULL`.

Comment: It should be noted that the form with explicit array dimension, although useful for didactic purposes, is not conventional.  Moreover, because the given dimension is not a constant expression, the declaration relies on the C implementation to support the variable-length array feature, which was introduced in C99 but made optional in C11.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you. I forgot that.

Comment: It's pedantic silliness. While this construction is, in a sense, a form of self-documentation, it's a petty, unnecessary one. Everybody knows what "argv" is -- in any real-world program there will be a gazillion things that need documenting more than this does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

argc stores number of command-line arguments passed by the user including the name of the program.
argv is array of character pointers listing all the arguments.It contains pointers to strings.Here argv[] and argv[argc+1] does not have any difference other showing the size  explicitly in argv[argc+1].The reason the author uses the first one is as a form of self-documentation of the code. It tells the programmer that the function has a precondition; the argv pointer should be pointing to the first element of an array of that length. argv is null pointer terminated.